# Ember-Rails gem in production on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

I am using Ruby On Rails 4 and Ember-Rails gem.
Everything works fine in development. In production deploying on Heroku, I get this particular error initializer.initialize is not a function and routes/templates aren't rendering.